# Julia Flux LSTM 2D Layer

Tags: julia

How can I use a 2D LSTM Layer in Flux.jl?

I tried doing:

```
julia> l = LSTM((10,4) => (10,1))
```

But that doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean an LSTM that simply accepts 2D input, you can flatten the array before feeding it into the LSTM layer:

```
using Flux, MLUtils;
x_dim = 10;
y_dim = 4;
num_samples = 3;
num_output_features = 7;

img = rand(Float32, x_dim, y_dim, num_samples)
model = Chain(MLUtils.flatten,
              LSTM(x_dim*y_dim => num_output_features))

size(model(img)) #(num_output_features, num_samples)
```